# Cleaning the log file on demand?

Tags: python, logging

I want to clean the log file on demand.
I have app that runs batches .. I want in the beginning of every batch run to clean the log file.

Is there a "logging" method for that or I have to do a shell command.
Will shell command interfere with file-descriptor that the "logging" module holds.

Overwrite-mode wont work, I want to do it on demand.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available out of the box because it's a rather unusual (so as not to say "strange") use case. Logs aren't supposed to be just deleted and overwritten right away - they're useless this way. You may be better off rotating the log instead:

```
h = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(<...>)
<logger>.addHandler(h)

<...>

for <batch> in <batches>:
   <...>
   h.doRollover()
```

---

That said, what you requested *is* possible with a non-public method of `FileHandler` that normally opens the log upon the handler's initialization:

```
h = logging.FileHandler(mode='w', <...>)   #or use whatever else creates a FileHandler, e.g. basicConfig()

<...>
h.close() #needed because it prevents side effects from the old descriptor
          #(e.g. garbage from unflushed writes, sharing violation)
h._open()
```